# How to use a loop where integers are inputted?

Tags: java

I'm working on a question and I'm new to programming, so I'm not that familiar with a few concepts. The question asks the user to input an initial number, followed by a list of that many numbers. The program should then print back how many of the numbers entered were negative.

For example, I first input 5, followed by 5 other random numbers.

```
5
6,-9,28,-32,-1
```

The output should be

```
3
```

So far all I have is:

```
class main 
{ 

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int input = scan.nextInt(); 
        int c=0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++) 
        { 
             System.out.println(i); 
             if(i<0) 
             { 
                 c++; 
             } 
        } 
        System.out.println(c); 
    } 
}
```

I'm really confused. Can someone offer an explanation as to how the code works?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking about. "we do what we are supposed to do"  so we can get it done.

Comment: I'm unsure of what operations I'm supposed to do, hence why I'm asking for an explanation aswell so I can use the knowledge to understand the code. My question is how would I approach a question like that? My way doesnt work

Comment: Think as a human how would we count black balls from a sack of black and white balls. Or how many students get 50+ within 100 in an exam :)

Comment: Ok, what *does* it do or not do?

Comment: So far I have a general idea that I need to select all values under 0 to appear. as in I'd assign an int x=0; and add one on everytime my variable <0. Then at the end i could use System.out.println(x) to give me my answer. But my question is how the heck does the loop work? How do I get the program to allow the person to select the numbers?

Comment: Like I'm struggling to understand how when the person inputs the first value (say 8), how do they input 8 different values after that?

Comment: That's what the loop would do. You need a single input like your first, except you just need to count the ones that come in <  0 like you're doing. So instead of outputting `i`, get the input.

Comment: So instead of (if(i<0) I should have (if(input<0)? When I do that and run it after compiling, the program just ends up counting down until zero. Like if i put in "3" I get "3,2,1,0,"?  I'm really sorry for asking so many questions, I just really am struggling to understand how the loop works in this case :/

Comment: You have to get another input every time.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh I got it now! Thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the positive integers inside `for loop` from the given inputs and then check if that each input integer is greater than or equal to zero:

```
        scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
                int input = scan.nextInt(); 
                int c=0;
                for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++) { 
                    int num =  scan.nextInt();              

                    if(num>=0) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println(num); 
                    } 
                }
```